# Using setters in constructor of an entity class

Tags: java, constructor, setter

I have this entity class (Netbeans 8):

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public User() {}    

    public User(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

}

The compiler warns me that I should not call overridable methods in a constructor, and I understand the reasoning behind it.

I cannot make the class final because is an entity, and making the setter final issues the warning that "The setter method for a persistent attribute must not be final."

I can asign the field directly, of course, but the setter performs a validation that I don't want to replicate in the constructor.

Any way of doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static factory method

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public User() {}    

    public static User createUser(String name) {
        User result = new User();
        result.setName(name);
        return result;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This method cannot be called from a subclass constructor, so there will be no warning about the overridable setter.

Comment: Yes, a factory will work fine. It's interesting though that apparently there is no right way of using setters in constructors in an entity class. I will check bean validation out too.

Answer (score 0):

The way you doing currently also fine,just ignore the warning and proceed.
(And I cannot post comments that's why I put in an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not wrong.But you can direct access your variables in the constructor.And you can also use "telescoping constructor pattern". See sample,

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int age;

    public User() {}    

    public User(String name) {
        this(name, age);
    }

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: But that does not solve the question. I want to use setters in the object creation logic because the check the validity of the arguments passed.